# Вопрос по сетке Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как колонку расширить до ширины браузера?

https://rawgit.com/ivanzabrodin/dreams/master/index.html
Хотел бы расширить до конца картинку айпада, которая в секции портфолио.

Comment: А можно только с одной стороны растянуть? А с другой чтобы так все и оставалось

Comment: `.portfolio .container: margin-right: 0;`

Answer (score 2):

В секции portfolio:

```
<div class="container">
```

меняйте на:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

более подробно [на офф документации bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: с какой растянуть, а с какой оставить Вам требуется? для этого тот же fluid только margin выставьте в одной из сторон

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `<div class="container-fluid">` с `padding: 0;`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?